# Symbolic summation in matlab

Tags: matlab, series, symbolic-math

I'm using MATLAB R2014b. I pasted code from example in documentation:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symbolic-summation.html

```
syms x
assume(x > 1)
S_sum = sum(x.^(1:10))
S_symsum = symsum(x^k, k, 1, 10)
```

and I got an error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'k'.

Error in SymbolicExperience2 (line 4)
S_symsum = symsum(x^k, k, 1, 10)
```

How do you think what's wrong? Should I migrate to MATLAB R2016b? Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That documentation page assumes you're working through the entire page, not starting midway, hence you missed the declaration of `k` as a symbolic variable:

```
syms k
syms x
assume(x > 1)
S_sum = sum(x.^(1:10))
S_symsum = symsum(x^k, k, 1, 10)
S_sum =
x^10 + x^9 + x^8 + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x
S_symsum =
x^11/(x - 1) - x/(x - 1)
```